# Have forgotten name of manga / Manhwa / light novel where MC can carry a whole shop in his bracelet

Tags: story-identification

I dont even remember if its a manga, manhwa or a light novel. All I remember is that towards the beginning MC discovers himself in a world he remembers, he travels in a specific direction and finds a specific shop that once sold weapons. The master of the shop is missing. Its run by a elf girl. There are knights of some sort in the shop when he arrives. It turns out the MC himself is the owner of the shop. He doesnt reveal it to the knights. He later starts travelling with the girl in tow - and he can turn that shop into a miniature that hangs from his bracelet. The store/guild's name probably has something to do with moonlight. Does anyone know any manga /manhwa/ light novel with a beginning like that?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is [The New Gate](https://myanimelist.net/manga/82427/The_New_Gate).

The main character, Shin, was playing a virtual reality MMO that had stopped people from logging out. Upon beating the final boss, instead of being able to log out he is thrown into the world of the game for real.  He uses a skill to head to his home/shop *The Moon Shrine*.  When he arrives, he finds it full of knights looking for the person they believe is the owner of the shop.  They leave soon after, and he talks to the elf girl at the counter.  After finding out she is cursed, he uses purification magic on her to remove the curse.

Later on, Shin goes traveling with the elf girl. He transforms the shrine into a necklace with a crescent moon on it.

Comment: You are absolutely right!!! Thank you thank you thank you!!!! It was like a worm stuck in my head not being able to remember it!!! Really cant thank you enough